# My python code using tkinter is executing next line without waiting for the previous to complete

Tags: python, tkinter

The code is as follows:

```
def TrainImages():
    assure_path_exists(os.path.join(SYSPATH,"TrainingImageLabel/"))
    recognizer = cv2.face_LBPHFaceRecognizer.create()
    faces, ID = getImagesAndLabels("TrainingImage")
    try:
        recognizer.train(faces, np.array(ID))
    except:
        mess.showwarning(title='No Registrations', message='Please Register someone first!!!')
        return
    recognizer.save(os.path.join(SYSPATH,"TrainingImageLabel\Trainner.yml"))
    res = "Profiles Saved and trained Successfully"
    instructionLabel.configure(text=res)
    promptLabel.configure(text='Total Registrations Done  : ' + str(max(ID)))
    time.sleep(3)
    displayUpdate()
```

In the above code, the `instructionLabel.config` and `promptLabel.config` are written first so they should at least be executed before `sleep` but instead, the code sleeps for 3 seconds and then all of the prompts show at once. I wanted to show the Total Registration Done bit with the Profile saved prompt for 3 seconds and then overwrite those prompts with detailed info.

Is `sleep` not ideal in the situation and maybe it is stopping the entire code then and there and not just the following lines from executing?

Comment: It is recommended you do not use `sleep` in a Tkinter app. Use `after` instead. This is because `sleep` blocks the ui thread and it can't update. `after` allows the ui thread to continue, then runs the command after the delay. Example: `root.after(3000, displayUpdate)`.

Comment: Beside the point, but [a bare `except` is bad practice](/q/54948548/4518341). Instead, use the specific exception you're expecting like `except ValueError`, or at least `except Exception`.

Comment: Pretty much NOTHING in Tkinter has an immediate visual effect.  Only when you return to the mainloop, or explicitly call something like `.update_idletasks()`, are events processed and the display actually updated.